# CSS Best Approach for 2 backgrounds?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a design that has some images across the top 25% of the background then it is just a simple gradient I can repeat for the rest.

What is the best approach to have the Images on the top, then fill out the rest of the page with the gradient?

I took this approach:

```
html{
    background: #cac2ac url("../img/body-bg.gif") repeat-y 50% 0;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    line-height: 1;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent url("../img/body-img-bg.jpg") no-repeat 50% 24px;
}
```

But in one implementation of the code the background image for HTML is not appearing?

Any help?

Comment: That's false, you CAN have a background on the HTML element. However, adding a top margin to it with a background image will cause bugs in old safari and IE8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to what has been said, you *can* have a background for `html`.

Your approach is almost there, try this with `height: 100%` and `min-height: 100%`.

http://jsbin.com/omikuy

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    background: #cac2ac url("../img/body-bg.gif") repeat-y 50% 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    line-height: 1;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent url("../img/body-img-bg.jpg") no-repeat 50% 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Cross Browser, but not semantic

The most cross-browser solution would be to have a wrapper `<div>` around all content in the website, and then apply one background to it, and one to the body.

## Less Cross Browser, but more semantic

You could also try using psuedo elements to apply one background:

```
body:after { background: .... }
```

## Least Cross Browser, but most semantic

The most progressive way is to use multiple backgrounds in CSS3

```
body { background: url(...) top center, url(...) top center repeat-y }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to have the body background your gradient and just create a div for the images with the following class:

```
.div_bg {

position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100px; (or whatever)
top:0px;
background-image:whatever; 
repeat:repeat-x;

}
```

And make sure HTMl has this (to elimate white space on top):

```
html {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```